# recursion widget in flutter tree

Tags: flutter

i am new in flutter.And i have a question.I callback widget(use MaterialPageRoute on the same widget).Is it bad to do recursion in flutter?I add a picture my render tree.I think it so bad,because i am using more and more resources of my phone.What should i do in this situation?Is this tree is normal for flutter?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your widget tree is normal for me, don't worry that. You will probably have more complicated trees in other projects.

Comment: its what im doing and im having issues. if i update the array lile adding an item, its the previvous screen's arrsy that gets rebuilt. weird. not sure what the cause is. if it might be provider related or what